# How to grab particular data from a website to Excel with queryselectorall

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

I am trying to transfer data from a website to Excel:

With my code I get all of the values of COL1:
10117 Berlin **AND**
Feydelstr **AND** Entfernung Nur für Kunden sichtbar

But how do I get access

- just to the **first two values** of COL1?
  (without the third value *Entfernung:),
- how to the **Pic in COL2**: <img src="/immobilien...musterfoto.jpg>
- and to the link in **<a class="entry  clearfix" href="/home/**

Hier is the part of the Website-HTML with COLs & values:

```html
         <div class="immobilien">
         .
         .
         .                                        
           <div class="clearfix">
           <div class="entry header"></div> 
           <a class="entry  clearfix" href="/home/immosuche~037.de.html>
            <div class="col1">                          
               <div>    
                 10117 Berlin                       
               <br>
                 Hauptstr.
               </div>                                               
               <br>
              <i>Entfernung:>
             </div>
           <div class="col2">
                <img src="/immobilien/file/4349ed6f753f82a501.jpg?>
              </div>
           <div class="col3">
                 Eigentumswohnung
           </div>
       <div class="col4">
           Keine Wertangaben
           <br>
```

My Code:

```
Public Sub GrGHTML()

    Const url = "https://www...."
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elm As Object
    Dim x As Long
   
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
       
        Set elm = Html.querySelectorAll("div.col1[class]")
        For x = 0 To elm.Length - 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 2) = elm.Item(x).innerText
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:**

> **just to the first two values of COL1? (without the third value**
> **Entfernung: Nur für Kunden sichtbar)**

**Answer:** Choose a child `div` element so you don't capture that additional line. `.col1 div`

---

**Question:**

> **how to the Pic in COL2: <img src="/immobilien...musterfoto.jpg>**

**Answer:** In the same way you selected "column 1" by class name, select "column 2" and then take the child `img` element, `.col2 img`, and extract the `src` attribute

---

**Question:**

> **and to the link in <a class="entry clearfix" href="/home/fuer_priv...**

**Answer:** Take the `a` tag elements with class `entry`: `a.entry`.

---

**General:**

These provide matching length nodelists so you only need to loop one list and index into to the others during the loop.

Use more meaningful variable names.

Complete the uris by replacing the about: with protocol + domain

Correct your url in post

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GrGHTML()
    Const URL = "https://www.argetra.de/home/fuer_privat/immobilien-suche~ae23f6bb38cb10bf01399d6fef892037.de.html?plz_ort=Berlin"
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
   
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
       
    Dim locations As Object, images As Object, links As Object
    
    Set locations = html.querySelectorAll(".col1 div")
    Set images = html.querySelectorAll(".col2 img")
    Set links = html.querySelectorAll("a.entry")
    
    With ActiveSheet
    
        Dim x As Long
        
        For x = 0 To locations.Length - 1
            .Cells(x + 2, 2) = locations.Item(x).innerText
            .Cells(x + 2, 3) = Replace$(images.Item(x).src, "about:", "https://www.argetra.de") 'Image
            .Cells(x + 2, 4) = Replace$(links.Item(x).href, "about:", "https://www.argetra.de") 'Links
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea that I should vote the useful answers, but I did it just now!

Comment: You can upvote up clicking the up arrow and accept by ticking the ✓

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a POST with your values for objectid, plz-ort, vw_ab, objektart,
vw_bis, umreis - not a GET.